# Setting up DD-WRT on NETGEAR R6400v2 Router for NordVPN - Telnet Issue

Tags: networking, router, vpn, internet-connection, dd-wrt

NETGEAR AC1750 Smart Wifi Router

- Model: R6400v2
- Base Firmware:
  V1.0.4.128_10.0.104

PC-Desktop:

- Windows 10 Home x64bit
- Ethernet Connection (Can Wi-Fi)

Router is not set as AP but is not only router on the network, I am using powerline networking.
Setup is as follows:

> Modem -> PrimaryRouter1 (wifi)
>
> **Modem -> PowerlineNetworking AdapterIn -> PowerlineNetworking AdapterOut -> SecondaryRouter2(Attempting VPN) -> PC**

**End Goa**l: Set up R6400v2 NetGear router as a VPN router using NordVPN.

**Problem Explanation**: I am attempting to install the DD-WRT firmware, following the guide on DD-WRT site for this router - https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Netgear (guide is a .doc file you have to download from this link).

[image: Snippet of DD-WRT Site of .doc file]

I am attempting to enable Telnet using some 3rd party programs found here:

- https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/netgear/telnet.console
- https://github.com/insanid/NetgearTelnetEnable
- http://www.antinode.info/nte/index.html

I have attempted all 3, programs following their various formats/instructions, all along the lines of:

> Admin CMD, cd to location of .exe file [filename] m=[mac] n=[ip] u=[username] p=[password]
>
> or
>
> Admin CMD, cd to location of .exe file [filename]

Both fail to yield results, i get

> nte: FAIL.  No ACK message received.
>
> or
>
> nte: recvfrom() failed.
>
> nte: errno = 0, WSAGLA() = 10054.
>
> nte: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> or
> [blank - no response at all]

When I use PuTTY to try and connect using the following format:

[image: Snippet of PuTTY program]

- **Host Name**: routerip, same as used in CMD prompt
- **Connection Type**: Other - Telnet

#### How do I enable telnet on this router?

**Notes**: Firewall Disabled during this

Answer (score 0):

I found a new utility that works!

https://github.com/bkerler/netgear_telnet

Just follow the instructions on the page.

It enabled telnet on my Netgear R6400V2 for me.